# javascript timed loop w/setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, loops, timer

I'm trying to write a script to update an iframe every second. This is what I have so far, and for some reason it loads for a little while and then displays the number 14541 +/- 50 or so. The words "something" and "something else" also never appear on the screen.

Is it stopping at 14541 because of some built-in browser safeguard against infinite loops or something? Why is the timer not working correctly?

```
var c = 0;
var t;
timer();
document.write("something");
function timer(){
    if(t) { window.clearTimeout(t) }
    update_preview();
    c++;
    t=setTimeout(timer(), 1000);
    document.write("something else");
}
function update_preview(){
    prev = window.open("","preview");
    prev.document.open();
    prev.document.writeln("<html><head><title>live preview window</title></head><body>");
    prev.document.writeln(c);
    prev.document.writeln("</body></html>");
    prev.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call method timer as a parameter of function timer. You have to pass as parameter function timer:

setTimeout(timer,1000);

Dont use document.write is obsolete. Look at DOM and jQuery in order to manipulate with the page dynamically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I fixed the timer and now somehow it works at 0, and then redirects to a new page where it prints "something else" over and over, and a popup comes up that displays the increasing number.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
t=setTimeout(function(){timer();}, 1000);
```

or

```
t=setTimeout(timer, 1000);
```

or

```
t=setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
```

**The last one is an option that should not be used.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` after `timer`.

By putting `timer()`, you are calling the `timer` function immediately and assigning the **return value** (`undefined`, since you don't `return` anything in that function) to be the function executed when the timer runs out.

Instead, you should just put `timer`. This passes the function itself, rather than its return value, to be the function called when the timer runs out.

Also, for clarity, I would suggest putting the `function timer() {...}` bit *before* the initial call to `timer()`. JavaScript does this for you automatically (called "hoisting"), but it's easier to understand if you put the function definition first yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `t=setTimeout(timer(), 1000);` you are not passing `timer` to setTimout, you are passing the result of `timer`. You should use `t=setTimeout(timer, 1000);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason "something else" is not displaying is because when you're calling setTimeout and passing the function in, the `timer` function is processing immediately. The same thing is happening inside the function. So you're creating a non-terminating infinite recursive loop that will make your browser unresponsive.

Since you're running `setTimeout` on `timer` every time you run the `timer` function, which is every 1 second, instead of using `setTimeout`, you should use `setInterval`.

So your code would look like this:

```
var c = 0;
var t;
timer();

// call setInterval here to run the timer function every 1 second
t=setInterval('timer()', 1000);

document.write("something");
function timer(){
    if(t) { window.clearTimeout(t) }
    update_preview();
    c++;
    document.write("something else");
}
function update_preview(){
    prev = window.open("","preview");
    prev.document.open();
    prev.document.writeln("<html><head><title>live preview window</title></head><body>");
    prev.document.writeln(c);
    prev.document.writeln("</body></html>");
    prev.document.close();
}
```

So now instead of running setTimeout every 1 second, you're running setInterval once and it will process every 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use setInterval instead of setTimeout.